# python: Is it better to have one proper for loop or several oneliner for loops

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy

I have several lines of python code that look like this:

```
myVar1 = np.array([d['key1'] for d in D[0]['Log']])
```

All keys/values have the same length.

is it better (performance/cpu/memory) to make a single loop and import them, or better several one liners?

What do you think?

Comment: Unless performance is critical, just do whichever is more readable

Comment: Preference is always that - preference. And the [faq#dontask] say that these kinds of questions are not the kind of questions that should be asked here. (see [ask])

Comment: @InbarRose - What's all this about preference? OP is asking about performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) and measure it.